# Document Template Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, document-template

When I want to create a document using my custom content type, I get this error. How can I resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you check the ULS logs for more helpful error messages?

Comment: Just checked ULS logs. I saw something like this


][User-agent: GUID={1984108C-4B93-4EEB-B320-919432D6E593}, OfficeBuildNumber=14.0.6126.5003 requestVersion=12][StreamSizes: Request=71836 bytes, Response=301 bytes][TotalRequestTime: 78msec][PartitionID: Default][Request: PutChanges Result=ICellError: cellerrStorageFailure (0x15), Chained=HRESULT: 0x81072114][Coalesce: Ran with result=Win32: 0x81072114 in 62msec (ClientRequested, NonHotAwarePartition, NewFile)]


What does "cellerrStorageFailure" mean?